# Post an amp-form with a templated url

Tags: amp-html

We have a searchbar made with an amp-form and an input text. On validation, we want to redirect the page on the mobile site, but we don't find a way to templatize the url with something like this :

```
<form method="get" action="https://example.com/search/'+searchword+'.html'">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="searchbar">
</form>
```

Of course, we can't change the url, to pass the param in query string.

So far we tried to use the amp-bind, but form [action] isn't a valid target.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is how it should work or if it is possible, but in their [example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-form/#form-submission-with-page-update) and this [tutorial](https://searchwilderness.com/amp-forms/#grefhttps://searchwilderness.com/amp-forms/#gref) it should be a fixed url. From there, you should be able to do what you want after a successful / error result. You can also check their samples so you'll be guided on how to implement amp-forms correctly and adjust it in relation on how your app should behave. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the URL directly, but `amp-form` will append your input field values to the URL as query parameters. This form:

```
<form method="get" action="https://example.com/search/">
  <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="searchbar" name="query" value="hello">
</form>
```

results in the following request URL: `https://example.com/search/?query=hello`.

I'd also suggest filing a feature request [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/new) for enabling bindings to the form actions.